# parallelize each iteration in MCMC

Tags: sampling, mcmc, parallel-processing

Suppose that I am using MCMC to sample from some distribution whose full conditionals can be written as:
$$f(\beta|\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{K}),$$
$$g_s(\alpha_{s}|\beta) \mbox{ for }s=1,\ldots,K,$$
and the **computation of sampling is dominated by $g_s(\alpha_{s}|\beta)$'s**.

Apparently we can first sample each $g_s(\alpha_{s}|\beta)$ separately (in parallel) within each iteration and collect $\alpha_{s}$'s, and then sample $f(\beta|\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{K})$. We can do this in each iteration of the MCMC.

My understanding is that there is a lot of communication (collecting $\alpha_{s}$'s and then sampling $f(\beta|\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{K})$) going on. Hence the parallelization needs not be very efficient.

I was wondering to how much extent do I need to worry about the communication in-efficiency in this scenario. Is there a better way to improve the sampling efficiency? Any suggestions would be really welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to move this to stackoverflow

Comment: this question is heavily programming language and specific example depedenent I doubt you will get a good answere here on on stack overflow. I suggest you try it out and if it works great...

Comment: It may be genuinely straddling both worlds. If the OP could give a real example of what they mean, this would probably work better. I can see when say sampling $\beta$ is a multivariate normal, while sampling $\alpha$ is some weird Metropolis-Hastings with extra complications -- random effect models may have this kind of structure, or may be some other situation where you have to calculate the necessary stuff by may be numeric integration. I smell that the solution may be problem-specific, and exploit the specific shape of the conditional for $\alpha$.

Comment: @Taylor It is about programming, but it is also very statistical-oriented problems. So for it to be answered, you'd need someone who is good at programming *and* in statistics, having deep knowledge of MCMC in particular -- I guess most programmers do not have deep understanding of MCMC.

Comment: @Tim and the others, OP seems to be deliberately abstracting away the statistical details, though.